I found a strange phenomenon in my SPSC with lock-free
I tried to implement a SPSC with lock free tech And got a quirky Segmentation fault. the code following:
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>

#define MATTER_NUM  10000
#define BUF_LEN 1024

uint64_t RingBuffer[BUF_LEN];
//uint32_t m_buffer[BUF_LEN];

std::atomic<uint64_t> head(0);
std::atomic<uint64_t> tail(0);


bool Push(const uint64_t &data) {
         uint64_t tmp_tail = tail.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
         if ((tmp_tail + 1) % BUF_LEN == head.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) return false;
         RingBuffer[tmp_tail + 1] = data;
         tail.store((tmp_tail + 1) % BUF_LEN, std::memory_order_release);
         return true;

}

bool Pop(uint64_t &data) {
      static uint64_t cnt = 0;
      uint64_t tmp_head = head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
      if (tmp_head == tail.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) return false;
      data = RingBuffer[tmp_head];
      head.store((tmp_head + 1) % BUF_LEN, std::memory_order_release);
      cnt = (tmp_head + 1) % BUF_LEN;
      return true;
}

int Producer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MATTER_NUM; i++) {
        while (!Push(i));
    }
    return 0;
}

int Consume() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MATTER_NUM; i++) {
        uint64_t data = -1;
        while (!Pop(data));
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(Producer), t2(Consume);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}

There are a quirky phenomenon. When I cancel the comment "uint32_t m_buffer[BUF_LEN]" in line 10, the code magically normal run! I can't understand why this is happening.
Build in g++ (GCC) 7.5.0:
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

Have you tried to use a debugger to catch the crash and see when and where it happens, and to examine the values of all involved variables? Most likely you either go out of bounds, or have a data-race. Both leading to undefined behavior.

I believe you have data-race leading to a buffer overflow or underflow. Since there's no synchronization between the threads, one of them might get an index that is either zero or the max (depending on the function) which is then decreases (or increases) to go out of bounds. Only the individual access to tail and head is atomic, not the Push and Pop functions themselves.

cnt in Pop appears to be effectively unused - it's a write-only variable. But given the other issue in Push, this seems to be due to a common cause: misunderstanding what % does, or confusing it with %=

RingBuffer[tmp_tail + 1] = data; - needs a %BUF_LEN. You have the occasional buffer overrun.

I think that RingBuffer[tmp_tail + 1] = data;  does  not need a %BUF_LEN. Because tail.store((tmp_tail + 1) % BUF_LEN, std::memory_order_release); had %BUF_LEN.

@MichaelFang: That's not at all how C++ works. I'm really puzzled how you think that could work. If you're still working on learning C++ basics, lock-free multi-threaded programming is going to be too big a challenge.

Cloud you elaborate more clearly?  I think that  the tail has a limit "tail.store((tmp_tail + 1) % BUF_LEN, std::memory_order_release);" , so its range is between 0 to BUF_LEN. theoretically，it must not  out of bounds.

tail wraps around, yes. tmp_tail does not.

I know what you mean, and you're right，thx~~
